# Binding "this" the right way in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, export, this

My team is building a React application and we need a javascript middleware/module to manage the calls to our (C#) APIs.

There are alot of APIs and each of them has alot of methods.

"*The goal is to build a middleware that gives an easy access to each API*"

In order to avoid writing a huge javascript file with all the different APIs and methods, I decided to split the code in different files.

---

#### middlewear.js

```js
export default config => {
    const middleware = { config };
    return Object.assign(middleware , getFileApi(middleware), getDocumentApi(middleware) /*, ... */);
}
```

This file groups each API together.

The idea is to call it like this : `middleware.fileAPi.getFile(123)`.

---

#### file-api.js

```js
// getFileApi
export default middleware => ({
    getFile: getFile.bind(middleware),
    getFiles: getFiles.bind(middleware),
});
```

This file returns an **Object** that contains all the methods from the **File api**.

In order to use the keyword **this** in these functions, I binded each of them to the **middleware**.

> I need to use the configuration at the root of the **middleware**.

---

#### getFile.js

```js
export default async function(model) {
    // I need to use the `config` from "api.js" in here.
    let someCode = this.config.baseUrl + someOtherCode;
}
```

> The **this** refers to the **middleware**. This way, I can access all that properties passed to the **middleware**.

---

### Problems

- I would like to rewrite the code above in a more clever way.
- I don't like to bind each function to the **middleware** like that, I would like it to be more transparent if possible.
- I have quite a lot of smaller **api**-s. It looks like this :

```js
export default config => {
    const api = { config };
    return 
        Object.assign(
            api, 
            getFileApi(api));
            getDocumentApi(api));
            getAudioApi(api));
            getSomeApi(api));
            getSomeOtherApi(api));
            getYetAnotherApi(api));
            getWoohooApi(api));
}
```

Thanks!

---

## EDIT

I found a way to fix some issues, but I don't know if its optimal.

```js
// Middleware 
// ================================================
export default {
  getFileApi: appConfig => getFileApi(buildConnect(appConfig))
};

// getFileApi 
// ================================================
export default (connect) => ({
    getFile: connect(getFile)
    getFiles: connect(getFiles)
});

// getFile 
// ================================================
export default (config) => async (data) => {
    const url = config.url;
    // return await ...;
}

// buildConnect
// ================================================
export default (appConfig) => {
    const initalConfig = { /* ... */ };
    const config = Object.assign({}, initalConfig, appConfig);
    return function(func) {
        return params => func(config)(params)
    }
}

// Usage (in react app)
// ================================================

import middleware from "...";
import appConfig from "...";

// usage
middleware
    .getFileApi(appConfig)
    .getFile(123)
    .then( /* ... */ )
    .catch( /* ... */ );
```

I use **closure-scope** to pass the configuration.

Well, I'm not an expert with Javascript so maybe I'm missing a more clean solution...

Comment: It's unclear why there's a bunch of all those APIs and what are they, and the question doesn't explain that, so this may be XY problem. Could be reasonably solved with class inheritance. *To avoid writing 5k lines of code in there, I decided to split the code in some smaller files* - this isn't a solid reason to mangle a class. There's nothing wrong with a big class if it's well-designed, but the code could be split to helper functions if necessary, and this won't require those detached methods that still rely on `this` context.

Comment: I find the whole construct a bit confusing, but there is no need at all to call `bind` if the functions are invoked as methods.

Comment: Hi @estus, I added more details on the "why". Also I may have found a way with a helper function. I will post it soon!

Comment: @estus, I would like to use **composition** over **classes**. I found it to be a good exercice for me.

Comment: I don't think that composition pays off here because this is a case for class design. It's not a very good approach for functional composition to rely on `this`. You're still doing classes' job but in less consistent way.  As it was mentioned above, it's unclear from the code above why bind is necessary. `middleware.fileAPi.getFile(123)` - getFile will naturally get proper `this` when being called like that. No binding is needed. Case closed, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like closure-scope would work better for yours situation.

**getFile.js**

```
export default function(api) {
    return async (model) => {
        const someCode = api.config.baseUrl + someOtherCode;
    }
}
```

**file-api.js**

```
export default api => ({
    getFile: getFile(api),
    getFiles: getFiles(api),
});
```

Notice that `getFile` returns new function which access `api` variable instead of manipulate context with `bind`.

*Edit*:

I made modifications to your newest example, see if there is something helpful.

```
// Middleware 
// ================================================
const connectionConfig = buildConnectConfig(appConfig);
export const Middleware = {
  fileApi: appConfig => getFileApi(connectionConfig)
};

// getFileApi 
// ================================================
export const getFileApi = (config) => ({
    getFile: getFile(config)
    getFiles: getFiles(config)
});

// getFile 
// ================================================
export const getFile = (config) => async (data) => {
    const url = config.url;
    // return await ...;
}

// buildConnect
// ================================================
export const buildConnectConfig = (appConfig) => {
    const initalConfig = { /* ... */ };

    return { // or Object.assign({}, ...)
        ...initalConfig, 
        ...appConfig
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi @Piotr Lewandowski! The team is used to writing heavy object oriented code and the **this** keyword reassures them haha. But you're right, the **closure-scope** would be the best in my situation. I've updated my question and added something I wrote yesterday.

Comment: @Bird, Using `this` is fine inside of class in JavaScript but everywhere else it's confusing. Closure-scope is designed in much more predictable way. According to new example, could you add final usage of `Middleware`?